# Creating file archives with the right kinds of file extensions

Tags: java

I have a list of files, the files have the same names and are in various different formats like swf, jpg, gif and fla.
Each swf may contain **ONLY** a gif image, it's possible a JPG image that does not have SWF, which should be listed.
 For example:

file1.fla
file1.gif
file1.jpg

file2.jpg

The output should be: 
BasicDBObject 1 shall contain: `file1.fla` **AND** `file1.gif`
BasicDBObject 2 shall contain: `file2.jpg`

I developed my code, but it seems to me full of For's and If's, probably the sonarQube generates an issue. Is there a better logic to apply and refactor it to have fewer lines of code?

```
private BasicDBList generateBDObject(String validacaoId) {
        List<Criativo> arquivos = criativoDAO.getAll(validacaoId);
        BasicDBList allFiles = new BasicDBList();
        List<String> auxiliar = new ArrayList<>();
        if (arquivos != null && !arquivos.isEmpty()) {
            for (Criativo criativo : arquivos) {
                for (int i = 0; i < criativo.getArquivos().size(); i++) {
                    if (criativo.getArquivos().get(i).getExtensao().contentEquals("swf")) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < criativo.getArquivos().size(); j++) {
                            String myFile = criativo.getArquivos().get(j).getExtensao();
                            if (myFile.contentEquals("gif")) {
                                BasicDBObject swfObject = new BasicDBObject();
                                swfObject.append("id", Util.getMd5Time(criativo.getArquivos().get(0).getNome()));
                                swfObject.append("path", null);
                                swfObject.append("nome", criativo.getArquivos().get(i).getNomeOriginal());
                                swfObject.append("pathOriginal", criativo.getArquivos().get(i).getPathOriginal());
                                swfObject.append("imagem", null);
                                allFiles.add(swfObject);
                                auxiliar.add(criativo.getNome());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                while (!auxiliar.contains(criativo.getNome())) {
                    BasicDBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
                    dbObject.append("id", Util.getMd5Time(criativo.getArquivos().get(0).getNome()));
                    dbObject.append("path", null);
                    dbObject.append("nome", criativo.getArquivos().get(0).getNomeOriginal());
                    dbObject.append("pathOriginal", criativo.getArquivos().get(0).getPathOriginal());
                    dbObject.append("imagem", null);
                    auxiliar.add(criativo.getNome());
                    allFiles.add(dbObject);
                }
            }
        }
        return allFiles;
    }
```

Criativo.java

```
public class Criativo {

    @Id
    String id;
    String tipo = "criativo";
    String validacaoId;
    String nome;
    String linhaCriativa;
    String veiculo;
    String formato;
    String canal;
    List<Arquivo> arquivos = new ArrayList<>();


    public String getTipo() {
        return this.tipo;
    }




    public String getLinhaCriativa() {
        return this.linhaCriativa;
    }

    public Criativo setLinhaCriativa(String linhaCriativa) {
        this.linhaCriativa = linhaCriativa;
        return this;
    }

    public String getVeiculo() {
        return this.veiculo;
    }

    public Criativo setVeiculo(String veiculo) {
        this.veiculo = veiculo;
        return this;
    }

    public String getFormato() {
        return this.formato;
    }

    public Criativo setFormato(String formato) {
        this.formato = formato;
        return this;
    }

    public String getCanal() {
        return this.canal;
    }

    public Criativo setCanal(String canal) {
        this.canal = canal;
        return this;
    }

    public List<Arquivo> getArquivos() {
        return this.arquivos;
    }

    public Criativo setArquivos(List<Arquivo> arquivos) {
        this.arquivos = arquivos;
        return this;
    }


    public String getNome() {
        return this.nome;
    }

    public Criativo setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
        return this;
    }

    public Criativo addArquivo(Arquivo arq) {
        this.arquivos.add(arq);
        return this;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public Criativo setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public String getValidacaoId() {
        return this.validacaoId;
    }

    public Criativo setValidacaoId(String validacaoId) {
        this.validacaoId = validacaoId;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Arquivo.java

```
public class Arquivo {
    @Id
    String id;
    String validacaoId;
    String nome;
    String tipo;
    String path;
    String extensao;
    String nomeOriginal;
    String pathOriginal;
    String dataCriacao;
    long tamanho;
    BasicDBObject atributos;


    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public Arquivo setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return this.nome;
    }

    public Arquivo setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
        return this;
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return this.tipo;
    }

    public Arquivo setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
        return this;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return this.path;
    }

    public Arquivo setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
        return this;
    }

    public String getExtensao() {
        return this.extensao;
    }

    public Arquivo setExtensao(String extensao) {
        this.extensao = extensao;
        return this;
    }

    public String getNomeOriginal() {
        return this.nomeOriginal;
    }

    public Arquivo setNomeOriginal(String nomeOriginal) {
        this.nomeOriginal = nomeOriginal;
        return this;
    }

    public String getDataCriacao() {
        return this.dataCriacao;
    }

    public Arquivo setDataCriacao(String dataCriacao) {
        this.dataCriacao = dataCriacao;
        return this;
    }

    public long getTamanho() {
        return this.tamanho;
    }

    public Arquivo setTamanho(long tamanho) {
        this.tamanho = tamanho;
        return this;
    }

    public String getValidacaoId() {
        return this.validacaoId;
    }

    public Arquivo setValidacaoId(String validacaoId) {
        this.validacaoId = validacaoId;
        return this;
    }

    public BasicDBObject getAtributos() {
        return this.atributos;
    }

    public Arquivo setAtributos(BasicDBObject atributos) {
        this.atributos = atributos;
        return this;
    }

    public String getPathOriginal() {
        return this.pathOriginal;
    }

    public Arquivo setPathOriginal(String pathOriginal) {
        this.pathOriginal = pathOriginal;
        return this;
    }
}
```

**Note**: `imagem` and `path` is null because it is in development. But `imagem` is equal to JPG image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could move some of the procedural logic into the objects. `BasicDBObject` could be returned by `Criativo`, such as a `toDBObject()` method instead of being converted outside by generateBDObject.

Collection inside `Criativo` or a predicate method could provide which have the "gif" and other desired requirements rather than evaluating in a loop: 
`if (myFile.contentEquals("gif")) {`